# undefined index in php (giving me notice)

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP: “Notice: Undefined variable”  and “Notice: Undefined index”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

Hello here is my code:

```
<?php
        // zmienna $go przekazana metoda GET
      $go = $_GET['go'];

      // sprawdzamy czy zmienna $go nie jest pusta
      if(!empty($go)) {
        // sprawdzamy czy plik o danej nazwie istnieje
        if(is_file("page/$go.php")) include "page/$go.php";
        // jezeli plik nie istnieje wyswietla się komunikat
        else echo "<br />Nie ma takiej strony.";
      }
      // jezeli zmienna $go jest pusta wyswietla się strona glowna
      else include "page/8.php";

    ?>
```

And I am getting error:

```
Notice: Undefined index: go in C:\xampp\htdocs\sz\index.php on line 32
```

The line number 32 is:

```
$go = $_GET['go'];
```

Any help? It's annoying.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if( isset( $_GET['go'] ) ){
 $go = $_GET['go'];
}else{
 $go = 8;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

John has posted a useful solution and good method to set up your code; but also I think after that error is fixed you may get another error by searching the wrong directory caused by:

```
if(is_file("page/$go.php")) include "page/$go.php";
```

A correction would be:

```
if(is_file("page/" . $go . ".php")) include "page/" . $go . ".php"; // would go to page/32.php
```

If you do not separate your variable from your string it would be trying to seek a wrong link.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check `isset($_GET['go'])` before attempting to access it. The code below addresses this issue.

```
<?php
if( isset($_GET['go']) && !empty($go) ) {
    $go = $_GET['go'];
    if(is_file("page/$go.php")) include "page/$go.php";
    else echo "<br />Nie ma takiej strony.";
}
else include "page/8.php";
```